# Login to Internal website and Scrap Data Behind Login Page

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and have been writing some test scripts to figure out things, I have managed to write test scripts to log in to a webpage and scrap the data however the code didn't seem to apply to my company's internal webpage. First of all, I was getting an SSH error which I managed to fix.

The following code manages to scrap the login page but I can't seem to pass the PayLoad. I am not sure if there is a better way to do what I'm doing as once I manage to get past the login page the website is dynamic and mainly coded in Javascript.

```
import requests 
import os.path 
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from urllib import request, parse 
import ssl

url = "https://10.43.52.106/3/Authenticate"
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

data = {'j_username': 'username',
'j_password': 'Password',
'j_newpassword': '',
'j_newpasswordrepeat': '', 
'continue': '', 
'submit': 'submit form'
} 
data = parse.urlencode(data).encode()

req = request.Request(url, data=data)
response = request.urlopen("https://10.43.52.106/3/Console", 
                context=context)
print (response.read())
```

I appreciate any help provided and know its going to best hard to test as its an internal webpage.
This is also the payload that gets sent when logging in:

[Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEzQJ.png)

Comment: That is not your code, because there are a number of mistakes.  You have `request` instead of `requests`, you have a missing comma in `(url data=data)`, you are creating a `req` but you never use it, and your `urlopen` call is not using any of the `data`.

Comment: Hello Tim, This is my code as I said im quite new, If you have any ideas how I can use this would be great

Comment: I'm not familiar with beautifulsoup, but I am familiar with Selenium. Have you tried selenium? It's an awesome package that can scrap webpage too. it can scrap value based on many things like CSS selector, element, id, and XPath. check out the doc